# Development folder drupal h5p

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I enabled the development folder in H5P in drupal 7. However, I don't know how to try the Hello World tutorial after I copy its three files: library, semantics and greetingcard (https://h5p.org/tutorial-greeting-card) to sites/default/files/h5p/development/H5P.GreetingCard/. If I go to any section in the drupal server I got:

Error message

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'databasename': LOCK TABLES {h5p_libraries_libraries} write, {h5p_libraries} as hl read; Array ( ) in H5PDrupal->lockDependencyStorage() (line 394 of /var/www/html/drupalsites/all/modules/contrib/h5p/h5p.classes.inc).
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your MySQL user doesn't have access to lock the tables. Make sure he is granted the *LOCK TABLES* privilege.

Good luck on the tutorial, it would be nice if you left some feedback for the creator when you're done :-)

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. And about how to try the Hello World component, I needed to go to Content, Add Content and then select Content type.